# uploading canvas base64 image on servlet

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets, canvas

I am uploading HTML5 canvas base64 image over servlet using following JavaScript code

```
function saveDataURL(a) {
    var postData = "canvasData="+a;
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST",'uploadPhoto.cgi',true);
    ajax.send(postData);    }
```

but on server when i see request.getAttribute("canvasData") its give me null value even when i debug java code request shows me null. What code should i write on Java, i have tried decoding Base64 request but as request itself contains nothing any help on code,tutorial much appreciated

Comment: can you provide some code example for urlencoding, what you think is this possible by using that. how can i send base64 data with url as its more than 256 char

Comment: Try `var postData = "canvasData="+encodeURIComponent(a);`

Comment: Hello Musa i tried above thing but still request is showing null, can suggest anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the url encoding set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
function saveDataURL(a) {
    var postData = "canvasData="+encodeURIComponent(a);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST",'uploadPhoto.cgi',true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send(postData);    
}
```